# How to get all the fonts used in a document using interop c#?

Tags: c#, fonts, ms-word, interop

I need to make an application which list all the fonts used in a document.

by using this code `var val = document.Content.Font.Name;` I am able to find the font name only if only one font is used through out the document. if multiple fonts were used the the value of val  becomes blank.

[Here](https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ah-Jh2Ok5SuHbpH5J6dEs4coHd0) I uploaded a sample file, in the document I used 3 type of font (Algerian,castellar, and Calibri). I need to find all three. I checked with Openxml there is showing the font name and I think i can get that but I have to use Interop only

XML from OpenXml

```html
<w:r w:rsidRPr="004E2690">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Algerian" w:hAnsi="Algerian" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Madan mohan Mishra</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Comment: You need to collect fonts from the Range objects that make up the document. There may be multiple fonts used even within a single paragraph. One possibility is to iterate through all characters in the text and check their font object. (It's been a while since I worked with Word, you may have to use Paragraph objects instead of Ranges.)

Answer (score 1):

Finding all used fonts can be rather complex, as there are so many locations within a Word document where a Font Object is applied (Open VBA from within Word, press F2 for the Object Browser and search for Font to see what objects within the Office Object Model carry the Font property)

This post might be of help for you, they already went over the whole exercise:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/list-fonts-used-in-a-particular-document/1f673f38-aa1d-4c4c-9e32-a2aec1bfbb96